# Jersey send login password on post request

Tags: java, post, jersey

I want make simle `jersey` form example. i have `login form` , `servlet` and`web service`. in `servlet - post` **request** `data` in `json`. `web service` control **login** and **password** and return `OK` or `UNAUTORIZED` as a `Response`.

> Login page

```
<form method="POST" action="login">
        Login <input type="text" name="login"/>
        Password <input type="password" name="password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="enter"/>        
     </form>
```

> Login servlet

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    name = request.getParameter("login");
    password = request.getParameter("password");
    isUser(name, password);
}
public void isLogin(String log, String pass) {
    Client cl = Client.create();
    String json = "{\"login:\""+"\""+log+"\",\"password\":"+"\""+pass+"\"}";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    WebResource wr = cl.resource("http://mywebservice/login");
    ClientResponse clr = wr.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class,obj.toString());

    System.out.println(clr.getStatus() + " ---- ");
}
```

> Service

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response isUser(String login) {
    //return super.find(id);
    JSONObject pb = new JSONObject(login);
    if (pb.get("login").equals("admin")) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

But don't work.Always return status 500.Where is my mistakes

Comment: is there any message appended with error code ? like invalid data input or something ??

Comment: now work thanks. and my another mistake is :
String json = "{\"login :\" "+"\""+log+"\",\"password\":"+"\""+pass+"\"}"; 
be
String json = "{\"login\" : "+"\""+log+"\",\"password\":"+"\""+pass+"\"}";

Comment: @VikrantKashyap you have facebook i need some help :/

Comment: please look google hangout

Comment: @VikrantKashyap look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this..

```
if (((String)pb.get("login")).equals("admin")) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
```

OR (any of these two as per your convenience) .

```
 if (pb.getString("login").equals("admin")) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
```

Instead of

```
if (pb.get("login").equals("admin")) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
```

> **Reason** :- `get("")` function of `JSONObject` returns `Object` Class Object so, `equals()` will belongs to `Object` Class not to the `String` Class. So, Change your Code re-Compile the code and see the difference.

Another Change what you should do to your method is add a @RequestBody to your `Parameter`. Probably it will resolve.

```
public Response isUser(@RequestBody String login);
```

Thanks :)